# What's the maximum character length of a MySql TEXT column?

Tags: mysql, text, innodb, string-length

I'm using MySql 5.5.37.  I have an InnoDB table with the following column

```
| MESSAGE  | text        | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
```

I'm noticing errors in our logs (we use Hibernate v5) that resemble

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'MESSAGE' at row 1
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4094) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar:]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar:]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar:]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar:]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2734) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar:]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar:]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar:]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar:]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar:]
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.CachedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(CachedPreparedStatement.java:115)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:493)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204) [hibernate-core-5.1.5.Final.jar:5.1.5.Final]
```

My question is, what is the maximum length (in characters) of a  TEXT column?

Comment: Did you make any attempt to search for the answer? The duplicate question title is almost identical to yours.

Comment: The max length is 64K _bytes_, which is somewhere between 16K and 64K `utf8mb4` _characters_.   Switch to `MEDIUMTEXT` to increase the limit.

Answer (score 5):

This question is about *characters*; the proposed "dup" is about *bytes*.  So, I reopened it.

The max length if a `TEXT` column is 64K *bytes*, which is somewhere between 16K and 64K `utf8mb4` *characters*.

Of you are using `latin1`, 64K.  If `utf8`, 64K/3.  Etc.

Switch to `MEDIUMTEXT` to increase the limit to 16M (or 16M/4, etc).